# What is the collective term for ironically cruel medical impediment names?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some nouns used in medicine ironically contain the letter that is difficult for the sufferer to say, or difficult to deal with:

- Lisp ('s')
- Rhotacism ('r')
- Blaesitas ('b')
- Dyslexia (difficult to spell)
- Hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia (fear of long words is a long word)
- Aibohphobia (fear of palindromes)
- Lamdacism ('l')
- Stammer/stutter (hard consonants easier to stumble over)

The closest I found was 'jocular terms', but this seems a bit too cruel. How did they come by these names? Is there a collective term that isn't so cruel?

I've looked at [this ESE question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264159/which-speech-impediments-contain-the-phonemes-affected-by-said-impediments) and [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/3fwdbr/til_the_inability_to_pronounce_the_letter_r_is/) hoping for an answer to this, but it didn't cover the collective term and more pointed out the cruel irony of it.

Comment: Maybe 'Irony'. :P

Comment: I won't write it as an answer but: "overly illustrative/cruelly instructive medical terms" might be helpful to you. Or perhaps just "cold medical jargon"

Comment: Interesting question John. One thing of note is that hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia is the "fear of long words" and Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian means "of or pertaining to long words".

Comment: These are all examples of *self-referential* terms (though not intentionally so). And the self-reference is ironic in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such term relating specifically to medical terminology. After all that would imply a level of sadism on the medical neologists which I am sure they lack!

However this idea, is a form of irony as mentioned, I would say it comes closest to: -

> Verbal irony

Where...

> Words [are used] to convey a meaning that is the opposite of the literal
>   meaning.

ref: [verbal irony](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verbal-irony)